# Access Eclipse project path with Pydev?

Tags: pydev

I have a Pydev/Eclipse project with a src/ directory and a data/ directory. Is there an easy way to access the full path of data/ (and the files there) from within a Python script (in src) without specifying the full data path explicitely?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

and then just remove the /src/ part and add /data/. It would technically be the full path but It would be working using the assumption that src and data are int the same top folder.

[Edit]

Something like this (if you are on *nix)

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
split_path = path.split('/')

new_path = ''.join([s + '/' for s in split_path[:-1]])
new_path += 'data/'
```

Guess it will be similar on Windows